# Kendo Datepickers inside ngFor

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have a list of 5 Datepickers displayed in `ngFor` loop.  When the user chooses a value I can see that the `let` value is being updated.  However, the backing model never gets updated.

My `app.component.ts` is very straightforward

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',

})
export class AppComponent {
    public value: Date = new Date(2000, 2, 10);
    public dateValues = [
      new Date(2019, 1, 1), 
      null, 
      new Date(2019, 3, 1), 
      null, 
      new Date(2019, 5, 1)];
}
```

As is the view:

```
<div *ngFor="let b of dateValues; let i = index">
    <div class="input-group registration-date-time">
        <kendo-datepicker class="form-control" [(value)]="b"></kendo-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let b of dateValues">
  <div>{{b}}</div>
</div>

<br/>
<kendo-datepicker  class="form-control" [(value)]="value"></kendo-datepicker>
VALUE IS: {{value}}
```

A live demonstration is here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pcquq which also shows a DatePicker updating field outside of the ngFor.

What needs to change so that the backing model in the look gets updated?

Comment: use `[(value)]="dateValues[i]"`

Comment: That causes another issue stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pcquq-ukuvrh

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your code:

```
<div *ngFor="let b of dateValues; let i = index">
    <div class="input-group registration-date-time">
        <kendo-datepicker class="form-control" [(value)]="dateValues[i]"></kendo-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but hat's actually where I started from this morning.  There is another issue where if you start with nulls and change a date, the text in the next datepicker gets set (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pcquq-ukuvrh)

Comment: woah... thats weird.. value dosen't actually change in the array.. it only shows on the picker.. @Joe